# Hide forms alternatively on click menu element

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to hide or show different forms in a web page. I have:

```
<ul>
     <li><a id="menu" href="#">Article1</a></li>
     <li><a id="menu" href="#">Article2</a></li>
</ul>
/*Here some forms*/  
  <div class="desc">
      <form>
      <input etc...>
      </form>
  </div>
  <div class="desc">
      <form>
      <input etc...>
      </form>
  </div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("a[name$='menu']").click(function() {
        var test = $(this).val();
        $("div.desc").hide();
        $("#"+test).show(); //maybe i could use slidetoogle
    }); 
});
```

I want to hide all other forms and show only the form linked on click. This code does not work!

Comment: ID should be unique.!

Comment: And i don't see `name` attribute anywhere in `<a>` tag

Comment: also `.val()` will not return innertext article1 and article2.It should be `.text()`

Comment: You can't use multiple ID with same name. Use only unique ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the id of anchor to class, i.e. `<a class="menu" href="#">`.

Now change the code to-

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $(".menu").click(function() {
        var test = $(this).text();
        $("div.desc").hide();
        $("#"+test).show(); //maybe i could use slidetoogle
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Work like a charm! Thank you Bikas ;)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$("a").click(function() {
    var test = $(this).text();
    $("div.desc").hide();
    $("#"+test).show(); 
  }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

as @Rajaprabhu Aravindasamy said you shouldn't use duplicate id's.

Instead Id use Class="menu" and change your selector as following code

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $(".menu").click(function() {
        var test = $(this).text();
        $("div.desc").hide();
        $("#"+test).show(); 
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Should be $(this).text() not val. See my answer

Answer (score 0):

Try it  Working http://jsfiddle.net/NjgQt/

```
<ul>
  <li><a id="menu" href="#form1">Article1</a></li>
  <li><a id="menu" href="#form2">Article2</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="desc" id="form1">
  <form>
    <input type="text" value="form1"/>
  </form>
</div>
<div class="desc" id="form2">
  <form>
    <input type="text" value="form2"/>
  </form>
</div>

$(document).ready(function(e) {    
    $('.desc:not(:first)').hide();
    $("a").click(function() {
        var test = $(this).attr('href');
        $("div.desc").hide();
        $(test).show();
    }); 

});
```